# XSLT file path to get XML value

Tags: xml, xslt

Is there a way I can avoid having to use the complete path to get the value in the XSLT document shown below? I was trying to edit the xsl:template match but was unable.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
    xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
    xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <AUTHENTICATOR>
        <USERINFO>
            <field name="Username" value="{/samlp:Response/saml:Assertion/saml:AttributeStatement/saml:Attribute/saml:AttributeValue[../@Name = 'UserName']}"/>
        </USERINFO>
    </AUTHENTICATOR>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample XML snippet:

```
<saml2p:Response xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
             Destination="https://login.com/Login/Authentication.aspx?configSet=SAML"
             ID="_5ed24fbfdeb20b1d0f98ed3d87f75dd8"
             IssueInstant="2015-10-26T18:19:38.218Z"
             Version="2.0"
             >
<saml2:Assertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
                 ID="_924982879ed0ee46ad33e21e674b2a65"
                 IssueInstant="2015-10-26T18:19:38.218Z"
                 Version="2.0"
                 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                 >
    <saml2:AttributeStatement>
        <saml2:Attribute Name="UserName"
                         NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri"
                         >
            <saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                  xsi:type="xs:string"
                                  >User@email.com</saml2:AttributeValue>
        </saml2:Attribute>
    </saml2:AttributeStatement>
</saml2:Assertion>
</saml2p:Response>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your expression as this...

```
<field name="Username" value="{//saml:Attribute[@Name = 'UserName']/saml:AttributeValue}"/>
```

Note how the condition on `@Name` can actually go against the `saml:Attribute` element here, rather than doing `../@Name` against `saml:AttributeValue`.

Alternatively, if it is guaranteed that there will always be a user name in the XML, you could also do something like this...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
    xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
    xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">

<xsl:template match="saml:Attribute[@Name = 'UserName']">
    <AUTHENTICATOR>
        <USERINFO>
            <field name="Username" value="{saml:AttributeValue}"/>
        </USERINFO>
    </AUTHENTICATOR>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The template matching `text()` is to ignore the text for any other `AttributeValue` elements that may occur in the XML.